# Painless Script Math.max change my data type

Tags: elasticsearch

I use **golang** "github.com/olivere/elastic/v7" package

xx_time is **uint32**  in my code

xx_time is **long** in es mapping

After update by script

```
ctx._source.xx_time = Math.max(ctx._source.xx_time, params.xx_time)
```

I get the same doc again get error

```
json: cannot unmarshal number 1.604394299E9 into Go struct field RiskInnerMachine.xx_time of type uint32
```

Get 1.604394299E9 not 1604394299  ,get 0.0 not 0.

I want to ask some question:

- Q1: Does Math.max change my data type ?  I even can't find any official document talk about which type the function return and how to use the function.
- Q2: Why the data can save in es ,if Q1 is true ,even the data is not a long data ?
- Q3: if Q1 is false, why I get the **float** data and other fields aren't affected ?

My solution is

```
ctx._source.xx_time = (long)Math.max(ctx._source.xx_time, params.xx_time)
```

I have to change the type manually. Make me pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. The Painless Math functions are described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.9/painless-api-reference-shared-java-lang.html#painless-api-reference-shared-Math), they are actually Java methods. Even though Java provides several overloaded `Math.max()` methods for `long`, `float` and `double`, Painless only provides the one for `double`, probably because all other types (i.e. `long` and `float`) can be upcast to `double`.

So yes, if you provide `long` or `float` values, Math.max will always return `double`. You can cast that value back to `long` as you do, which is not too much of a hurdle, I guess.

Q2. If you have `long` in your mapping, it's ok, because ES will [coerce](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) the `double` value into a `long` (enabled by default). And since the value actually represents and contains a `long` value, there's no information lost (i.e. 1604394299.0 coerced into 1604394299 doesn't remove any meaningful information).

Q3. -